# Open Highcharts xAxis link in new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm trying to create a link for the categories listed in xAxis in Highcharts

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar'],
            title: {
            text: 'Day of Month'
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return '<a href="http://www.google.com?q=' + this.value + '">' +
                        this.value + '</a>';
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [300, 200, 600]
        }]
    });
});
```

But the problem it's that i can't make to open the link in new windowd (even adding target="_blank"

Demo: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/highcharts/Example/Axis_Label/Format_axis_label_with_link.htm

Link: https://jsfiddle.net/6zd02pwo/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to manage labels yourself you might want to use plain HTML for them

```
labels: {
  formatter: function () {
    return '<a href="http://www.google.com?q=' + this.value + '" target="_blank">' +
                    this.value + '</a>';
  },
  useHTML: true
}
```

However this case you'll have to manage your styles youself as well

*UPDATE*

There's more hacky way if you want to use the same highcharts code and styles 
but there's no guarantee that it works in any following version as is

```
$('#container .highcharts-axis-labels:first tspan').click(function() {
    window.open('https://www.google.com?q=' + $(this).text(), '_blank');
});
```

Comment: Welcome! I posted an update  though I still would prefer the first option I think

Answer (score 0):

As said by Ignor, use custom labels. 
I just want to add context around the "this" in Igor's answer

Here is my code example

```
    //creating my names array (array of labels)
    var names = [];

    //ranging through result above then pushing each result into names
    names.push('<a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=' + result[i].ticker + ' target="_blank">' + result[i].name + '</a>');

    //here is the xAxis section of my Highcharts.chart(){}

    xAxis: {
       //names is an array of labels
        categories: names,
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        labels:{
        //pipe names array into function
          formatter:function(names){
        //call each value within names -- High charts is ranging through so no need to range through yourself
            return names.value;
          },
          useHTML:true
        }
    },
```